# How to call a method in non activity class from activity

Tags: class, android-activity, methods, call

I have a class which display a BottomSheetDialog with button on click open CustomisationActivity

```
class InfoDialog(private val activity: Activity) {

    private var bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog? = null

    fun show() {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, null)

        view.find<Button>(R.id.accept).setOnClickListener {
            dismissDialog()
        }

        view.find<Button>(R.id.customize).setOnClickListener {
            activity.startModal<CustomisationActivity>()
        }

        bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(activity).apply {
            setContentView(view)
            setCancelable(false)
            show()
        }
    }

    private fun dismissDialog() {
        bottomSheetDialog?.dismiss()
        bottomSheetDialog = null
    }

    fun closeDialog() {
        dismissDialog()
    }
}
```

And I need call from CustomisationActivity the method closeDialog()(in the BottomSheetDialog) when the user click on the button in the layout Activity.

Could please help me to do that?

Thank you very much

Bomatch

Comment: You can extend InfoDialog with DialogFragment and handle the event from activity using fragment instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
The problem is the leadDev and the rules of the application don't let me do that.
It seems to be able to use Callback but I don't know how to do in my case.

Comment: How this BottomSheetDialog show? You can use `LocalBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Thank very much for your quick reply.
This dialog can be call from any activity. And If user clic on customize button, that open a custom Activity. And if clic on Validate Button, I need to Close Dialog and if clic on backpress The dialog must be open.

Comment: Try LocalBroadcastReceiver

Comment: Thank you sasuke.
I try to propse this solution.
Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to launch `CustomisationActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`. When `CustomisationActivity` is complete, `onActivityResult()` will be called in the original `Activity` (that started the `Dialog`). You should be able to then call `dismiss()` on the `Dialog` from there.

Comment: The first class is not an Activity. Impossible to use onActivityResult.
But thank your for this proposition

Comment: What is the first class? There needs to be something hosting the Dialog

Comment: In fact, the first class can be any Activity. Because this Dialog is in a module used by application.

Comment: Your application architecture is probably broken. In any case, you could create a `BaseActivity` that contains the code to show the `Dialog` and an implementation of `onActivityResult()` that would dismiss it. All your other activities could then extend `BaseActivity`. There are simple ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your help.
Effectivly, I think the best is to do that.
I will try to propose this solution.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will help others who have a similar problem and will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Hello,Finally the choice is to close every time the Dialog. And put in Integration at onResume of activity need to call Dialog a "if" with good condition.
for exemple :
override onResume
if (needToDisplayDialog) {Show Dialog}
 
override on pause
dismissDialog